# How would a native speaker say, 'which is' or 'that is'?

Tags: english-to-japanese

An English example would be, `'We have seen a lot of changes, which are good for business.'` or a follow-up question in a casual conversation, `'..Which is?'`

I was wondering if they have an exact word or phrase for this, or do they have a similar concept?

Arigatou!

Answer (score 3):

This type of noun-modifying clause is called *relative clauses* (関係節 or 連体修飾節 in Japanese). The Japanese language has the same concept, but the word order is drastically different. [This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) is a quick starter, but this is a difficult topic which can take months to get used to, so I recommend reading your textbook.

<sub>(If you are already familiar with basic relative clauses and searching for the name of this special type of relative clause, please read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35755/5010). Note that this is an advanced topic to a beginner.)</sub>

As you will soon realize as you begin to learn this concept, Japanese relative clauses must be placed *before* the modified thing. Therefore, Japanese has no direct equivalent of 'Which is...?' as a follow up question said at the beginning of a sentence. Instead, you can just say "[つまり](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A9%B0%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A)…?" ("That is...?") to ask for the conclusive or summary statement.